# Button grows/flashes when I reload the page instead of just being fixed, why?

Tags: css

I am trying to fix the button in the page; when I reload the page the button seems to grow into its size and the text also starts blue and then goes into its intended color instead of just being there to begin with. I have had this problem before, but I figured I would see what I'm doing wrong. I have taken out the code up until the heading-primary-sub class and redid it, but I cannot see why this is happening.

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight:400;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:1.7;
  color:#777;
  padding:30px;
}
.header{
  height:95vh;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.795),#28b485),url(../img/hero.jpg) ;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: top;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75vh, 0 100%);
  position:relative;
}

.logo-box{ position: absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:40px;

}

.logo { height: 35px;

}

.text-box{
  position: absolute;
  top:40%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
  
}
.heading-primary{
  color:#fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin-bottom:60px;
}

.heading-primary-main{ display:block;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 35px;
  animation: moveInRight 1s ease-out;

}
.heading-primary-sub {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 15px;

  animation: moveInLeft 1s ease-out;
  
  /*
  animation-delay:3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  */
}

@keyframes moveInLeft{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform:translateX(-100px);

  }

  80%{
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }

  100%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(0);

  }
}

@keyframes moveInRight{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
    transform:translatex(100px);

  }

  80%{
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }

  100%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate(0);

  }
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited { text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:15px 40px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition:all .2s;
  position: relative;
  background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "fix" the button?

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening for any number of reasons - the code you posted is not giving us enough information to know what the problem really is. Can you post a link or any other relevant information (eg. are you using a CMS like Workdpress or an app boilerplate like create-react-app?)

The most likely culprit is you are loading styles in a non blocking (asynchronous) way... which is "good practice" a lot of the times. However, to prevent the jumpy "flash of unstyled content (FOUC)", you usually need to put a minimal set of styles directly in the HTML inside a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of your page.

In your case, you would do something like this directly in your html:

```
<head>
  ...other stuff 

  <style>
  .btn:link,
  .btn:visited { text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:15px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition:all .2s;
    position: relative;
    background-color:white;
  }
  </style>
</head>
```

UPDATE:
So there's really too much to try and cover here. You are trying to have a bunch of page elements animate on page load, and this is generally not for the feint of heart. Coordinating page load "intro" animations with how assets are loaded over the internet (eg. the google fonts and background images are loaded asynchronously), along with the timing and default styles... you're entering into a world of pain.

I can't go into all of the nuances of making this "right", but the short of it is that you need to hide all of your animated content until everything has loaded (fonts, images, etc). Then you are going to need to kick off the animation by hand. This is all going to require that you write JavaScript. Best of luck.

Comment: I have a link for my project folder. I am making this page using Visual Studio, I am not using a CMS.  https://github.com/Nero4123/Nero/blob/main/Broken%20Button.zip

Comment: I tried putting the suggested code in the format you suggested (within the html), and it almost fixed the problem. The problem is still present, but just to a lesser degree. The button still twitches for a second and the text still displays as blue for some reason. It is a lot better than before though.

Comment: OK - I've updated my answer. Unfortunately there's no simple solution to your problem. You need to understand how the browser loads things like CSS, images, fonts, etc, and then you need to know how browsers "paint" the page and how CSS animations are queued. Then you're going to need to write JavaScript to make things work the way you want.

Comment: One easy thing you can do is remove the `transition: all 0.2s` from the button. This is the reason you are seeing an unstyled button momentarily. The reason this happens is because a hyperlink is blue by default. When you say "transition: all" - the browser is going to transition from the default blue to the color you specified. The same thing is happening with the padding... which by default is 0 and then is animated to your value `15px 40px` - this is why the button appears to swell in on initial load.